# Disable warning "entity was modified, but it won't be updated because the property is immutable" when saving entity with fields marked updatable=false

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, logging

I have some fields marked with @Column(name = "column1", updatable = false) in entities in jpa repository, and it works as intended but when saving the entity a warning message like this is show:

```
2020-04-23 18:48:34.358  WARN 1112 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     : HHH000502: The [column1] property of the [com.nodobanka.core.data.model.Entity1] entity was modified, but it won't be updated because the property is immutable.
```

I just want to know How Can I stop this warning from printing in log?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set logging level for `org.hibernate.persister.entity` package to `ERROR`. That way it'll only display logs with `ERROR` and `FATAL` levels.

You can do this in [Spring by adding following line in application.properties file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels):

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.persister.entity: ERROR
```

Comment: Hi, that message log level was warn, using error dont display it, but it dont display other warn messages, looking for alternative solution but this works temporary, thanks

Comment: Hi, @Xiul! It's an old question? but actual for me ) Do you find alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use relation for updates (instead of FK field).

Kotlin example:

```
data class ... (
    ...
) {
    @Column(name = "market_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    var marketId: Long = 0

    /**
     * This field is used for updates instead of [marketId] to avoid warning about immutability
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "market_id")
    lateinit var market: NiceHashMarket
}

...

entity.market = Market(...)
```